# How to extract a number from string using regex in java

Tags: java

I have tried using

```
title.substring(title.lastIndexOf("(") + 1, title.indexOf(")"));
```

I only want to extract year like 1899.

It works well for string like "hadoop (1899)" but is throwing errors for string "hadoop(yarn)(1980)"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Why not use `lastIndexOf` for both parenthesis (assuming you are interested in data from last parenthesis)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi check [this](https://regex101.com/r/b9Xkab/1) example. This is regex for extracting numbers surrounded by brackets.

Here is usable code you can use:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(?<=\\()\\d+(?=\\))";
final String string = "\"hadoop (1899)\"  \"hadoop(yarn)(1980)\"";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: If u want to know more about regex used, check right sidebar, it explains what each symbol/char means.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace all but the digits within parenthesis with a regex

```
String foo = "hadoop (1899)"; // or "hadoop(yarn)(1980)"
System.out.println(foo.replaceAll(".*\\((\\d+)\\).*", "$1"));
```